# When do we need to use base_url() function in codeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, base-url

I am working on a small project and all of my urls are written without `base_url()` function. So I was thinking what does those `base_url()` functions help with my urls. I know it will prefix the url based on configs file preferences. But simply I wanna ask

What is the advantage of using them ? and whats the disadvantage of not using them ?

Comment: You'll probably never need it. Although there have been several times when I've had to move an exiting site from the root into a subdirectory. Doing so meant updating all the links by hand, if I had use base_url(), it would have saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage is that; when you want to migrate your project to online or in a different server; you won't need to edit your hard-coded links. The base_url() will make your inside links to get their base url dynamically.

```
echo base_url("blog/post/123");
```

will return

```
http://example.com/blog/post/123
```

in `example.com` and will return

```
http://jms.com/blog/post/123
```

in `jms.com`

Answer (score 1):

`base_url` is needed when  you create login/signup with email verification or forgot password functionality (Verifying by clicking the links like this http://yourdomain.com/auth/userid/code).
This is only one example, may have lot of uses.

Answer (score 0):

the difference of `base_url()` and `site_url()` is that

both returns the url of your site but `site_url()` returns your site url, with attached `index.php` or on what you have configured `$config['index_page'] = ''` 
in `application/config/config.php`

example `www.yoursite.com/chicken/turkey`

when using `base_url()`: Returns your site base URL, as specified in your config file.
you will get `wwww.yoursite.com`

when using `site_url()`:
you will get `www.yoursite.com/index.php`

`site_url()` is usefull if you haven't change your `.htaccess` and you still access your controllers with `index.php`

`base_url()` is usefull when linking your css,js,or media stuffs. Granting that you still use `index.php` when accessing your controller/method

Answer (score 0):

Its needed every-where, or at least we should use everywhere. Do you know, absolute url is far better then relative url? So, when you are using an absolute urls for all links on your site, instead of hard coded root domain name, you can use the "base_url()" function. Moreover, CI reactor is smart enough to detect the original base url, so you even don't need to enter it in config file.

Answer (score 0):

I usually using the **base_url()** for the correct paths to the static files (css, js, img) files and the **site_url()** for the links to pages. **site_url()** will return with `url_suffix` witch could be set in **application/config/config.php** file

Answer (score 0):

Advantage:-if you not use base_url() and you want to switch directory/server of your site , you should change the path all over the project.

if you use base_url(), just change it at onece in config.php ,effect on all site.