# Why you should use base_url() in relative links (Codeigniter etc.)

Tags: php, codeigniter, relative-path, base-url

Why in relative links I should always use syntax *base_url*+link in CodeIgniter?
For example:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>link22.php">
```

instead of

```
<a href="/link22.php'>
```

when I've got declared `<base href="<?php echo base_url()?>">` in HTML head?
What are the benefits?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14764975/when-do-we-need-to-use-base-url-function-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question.

***Short words*** (used in below)

CI - Codeigniter

---

### Why you should use `base_url()`??

`base_url()` is a the function which determine your project destination which act as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in php. This will know where your actual project contains.

---

### Where we can modify/define `base_url()`??

```
Path - application/config/
File name - config.php
```

---

### Can We just use `base_url()` function?

No. You can't. In CI they having some **libraries** and **helper** which help us to use CI more friendly. So to `base_url()` there is an **helper** file call **`url`**.

**How to load it??**

```
Path - application/config/
File name - autoload.php
```

there is function like this `$autoload['helper'] = array();`. So add the helper to that

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');
```

---

### Is there any method to modify/define `base_url()`??

Yes. There are two methods you can define `base_url()`

**Method 01**

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

**Method 02**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/foldername/';
```

**Difference between *Method 01(M1)* and *Method 02(M2)***

*M1* - When we keep empty `base_url` it will automatically determine your project scope. So when ever you can't find path or having some doubt this is recommend.
*M2* - There is no difference between M1, In here you know path. So can define it.

**Which method is good/recommended?**

As my suggestion is **Method 01** is the best.

---

### Why we use `echo base_url()` instead of just `base_url()`

`base_url()` is an variable which *pre+defined*(Codeigniter+User) in CI framework, which we can use entire project. So to show content of variable in `php`, we use `echo`. In here also same theory comes to this.

---

### Why this `<a href="/link22.php'>` will not work

Codeigniter Framework build with **MVC** Structure. (**MVC** stand for **M**odel **V**iew **C**ontroller.)

So when open your project it will call to **Controller**, then if there any incoming values from Database. It will get that from the **Model**, Then it will load relevant **view** which mentioned in **Controller**.

If this `link22.php` is some related file to your project you have to place that inside **View** folder.

---

### Can I include php file to another view

Yes. you can. For that you have to use `APPPATH`.

Example - Assume `link22.php` is inside `view/links/` So you have to use

```
APPPATH.'view/links/link22.php'
```

---

Some Usefull links

1. [URL Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html)

Answer (score 3):

there are times when you are developing you will have a folder structure for different versions like:
localhost/dev/ or 
localhost/beta/

and your live website might be a different naming like 
epicapps.com/preview/

by using base_url() you can map to localhost/beta/ on your local copy,
and epicapps.com/preview on your public server.

hint: you can set base_url on your main index.php page. like

```
$assign_to_config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/beta/';
```

and make sure that in application/config.php the base url is blank.  `$config['base_url'] = '';`

then you can push any changes from your local application folder to the server application folder, and the config file in applications will not mess you up, because base_url is being defined in the main index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this out use this if anyone finds this helpful
if you're using a custom port on your localhost
mention in your

> application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:portNo';
```